# Pandas window aggregation two sorted tables

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I've got two tables, for example

Table A with fields A,B (sorted by A count):
A,B

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| foo1 | a |
| foo2 | b |
| foo3 | a |
| foo4 | d |
| foo5 | c |
| foo6 | a |

Table B (sorted by B count):

| Column B |
| --- |
| a |
| b |
| c |
| d |
| e |

I want to get a table like this (to get top 2 most popular A for each B):

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| foo1 | a |
| foo3 | a |
| foo2 | b |
| foo4 | d |
| foo5 | c |

I tried to do aggregate and groupby, but I have no ideas how to create this.

Comment: what is connection between both DataFrames?

Comment: connection by column B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC use ordered [`Categorical`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html), then sorting by this column and get top2 values by [`GroupBy.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html):

```
df['Column B'] = pd.Categorical(df['Column B'], 
                                ordered=True, 
                                categories=df['Column B'].unique())
```

If order is necessary use from another `DataFrame` use `categories=df2['Column B']`:

```
df['Column B'] = pd.Categorical(df['Column B'], 
                                ordered=True, 
                                categories=df2['Column B'])
```

---

```
df = df.sort_values('Column B').groupby('Column B').head(2)
print (df)
  Column A Column B
0     foo1        a
2     foo3        a
1     foo2        b
3     foo4        d
4     foo5        c
```